# Android - background change from Java code

Tags: android, android-layout

my problem is, I have custom listView filled from Runnable returnRes. It fills particular data in layout I have named as lay (R.id.layoutList). My aim is to have different colour for each lay in my listView, I want to switch colours between each. 1st is dark blue, second light blue, thir dark blue and so on... This code is doing well, but with no result, my custom listView is still black, when I change it in XML, it is changing, but not when it is set from Java. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(myTasks != null && myTasks.size() > 0){
            TasksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            LinearLayout lay=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutList);

            for(int i=0;i<myTasks.size();i++){
                TasksAdapter.add(myTasks.get(i));
                if(i>0){
                    if(i%2==0){
                        lay.setBackgroundColor(R.color.background);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(i>0){
                        lay.setBackgroundColor(R.color.lightBlue);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        TasksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  };
```

Comment: Try this somewhere in your Activity's onCreate():

`getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`
`getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Answer (score 1):

Try googling. `getResources().R.color.lightBlue` is not the actual color, it's the **id** of
the **color resource** (which is an integer code for the color).  It will work fine if you use it
in an API which expects ids of resources, but `setBackgroundColor`
actually needs the code of the color.

`colors` and `ids` are both just coded as `int` when you come down to it, so it's
really easy to confuse one for the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourbackgroundimage))
```